# Missing modules writing Python on iPhone

Tags: python, ios, iphone, module, python-datetime

I recently wrote a python script for my iPhone that looks at the schedule of my school's dining halls and tells me whether they are open or not.

I wrote it on the computer and planned to paste it in the app **Python Widget**, which allows you to display python output as a widget on the notification screen.

But when I ran it, it was missing the datetime module! Is there ANY way to get the datetime module imported into this app, an equivalent platform I could use, or alternatively, a way to rewrite the script without the datetime module
 (i.e. comparing times/dates using the time module)?

This works perfectly fine on my computer:

```
import datetime
```

But on the iPhone it's no good...any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.